# Ten numbers that each divide their sum

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Question: There are 10 different positive integers which are divisors of their sum. Identify these numbers.

My child have already found an answer using guess and check (and some luck). Please use relatively simple maths terms that can be understood by a grade 8 student. Her answer is {1,2,3,4,5,8,10,12,15,60}

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Note the set of $10$ positive integers is not unique. For example, with any set of $10$ which work, you can get another set of $10$ just be multiplying each one by a positive integer $\gt 1$. Similar to you, I've also come up with a set of $10$ integers using a certain amount of guessing & checking, but there's a good chance they'll be somewhat different from yours. As such, when you say you "found the answer", it'll be more correct to say you found an answer. Why don't you share your answer so others, like me, can compare our answers to it? Thanks.

Comment: Why stop at ten? $1,2,3,6,12,24,48,\ldots$ Keep on doubling.

Comment: Thank you John. My child's answer is {1,2,3,4,5,8,10,12,15,60}

Comment: Your work should go into the question body, John. Not in a comment where passers-by won't necessarily see it. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619) for pointers to new askers.

Answer (score 3):

One strategy is to start by expressing $1$ as an [Egyptian fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_fraction) with $10$ terms: 
$$1 = \frac{1}{a_1} + \frac{1}{a_2} + \ldots + \frac{1}{a_{10}}$$
Then if $N$ is divisible by all the denominators $a_i$, we can take the $10$ different positive integers $N/a_1, \ldots, N/a_{10}$, which all divide their sum $N$.

The Wikipedia article above shows strategies for obtaining such an Egyptian fraction.  For example, you could take
$$ 1 = \frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{15}+\frac{1}{24}+\frac{1}{30}+\frac{1}{40}+\frac{1}{60}+\frac{1}{120}
$$
leading to $$120 = 40+30+15+12+8+5+4+3+2+1$$

Comment: Nice answer... but do you really think a grade 8 child will understand that?

Comment: Maybe not in those words.  But Egyptian fractions can be explained to a bright grade 8 student.

Answer (score 1):

It's trivially simple once you see the pattern. Start with 1, 2, and 3. They add up to 6, which is divisible by 1 (obviously), 2 (it's even) and 3.

The next term is 6. $1+2+3+6 = 12$, which is divisible by 1, 2, 3, and 6.

The term after that is 12. $1+2+3+6+12 = 24$, which is divisible by all numbers in the sum.

You can probably see where this is going. Adding two values that are divisible by the same number will produce another value that is *also* divisible by that number. Since we're adding the sums of all previous values in the series, we're putting in numbers we already know are divisible by every number that's already there. And since we're effectively adding the new term to itself, our sum will just be equal to double the last term, and therefore divisible by it.

This isn't the only way to do it, of course, but it's the most convenient and lends itself well to continuing the series indefinitely.